# How to reference a theorem's items in Italic in the text?

Tags: environments, theorems, italic, ref

I have a theorem with different items in Roman numbers

[image]

I want to use  `\ref{}` to reference one of these items in the text. I use the following code, and I get this reference (highlighted part) non-Italic.

> How can I have this  `\ref{}` in Italic?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newenvironment{thmenum}
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(\arabic*),ref=\thethm(\arabic*)]}
 {\end{enumerate}}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
We have:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item \label{th1} abcd.
\item \label{th2} abcd.
\item \label{th3} abcd.
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}


I want to have \ref{th2} in italic form.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @Mico Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking for something that's rather questionable from a typographic point of view. However, if you are really, really sure that this is what you want, you may achieve your formatting objective by changing

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
```

to

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),ref=\textit{(\roman*)}]
```

I would actually recommend you take the opposite route, i.e., render the roman numerals in the upright font shape in the theorem statement, by using

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textnormal{(\roman*)}]
```

That way, "(ii)" will be rendered in the upright text font shape in both the theorem statement itself as well as in cross-references elsewhere in the document.

Comment: In full agreement that the item labels should be roman throughout.  (Personal opinion, but backed up by decades of working with typesetting for a mathematical publisher.)